# Handle button click inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I can't seem to handle a button click properly inside a custom UITableViewCell. It's a cell that contains a label and a button. I have the following code:

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellKey) as ApptHistoryCell;
if (cell == null)
{
    cell = _container.Cell;
    cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
}

if (InfoClicked != null)
{
    cell.ActionButton.TouchUpInside += InfoClicked;
}
```

InfoClicked is an event handler passed on in loop on cell creation. When the cell is re-used, this causes a null reference exception, because (I think) TouchUpInside is trying to call 2 handlers. Old one and the new one, which causes a crash. If I put the event handler inside cell == null if block, then the wrong action is shown.

How can I handle the click properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I handle buttons inside custom cells:

- I define an IBAction that I connect to a UIButton event inside the custom cell
- I define a delegate and a delegate method for the cell to handle the button action
- The IBAction calls that delegate method
- When defining your cells in cellAtRow... I set the tableViewController to be the delegate. cell.delegate=self;
- I do whatever action I would like to do inside that delegate method in the tableViewController

Makes sense?

Comment: Is there a way to get the indexPath of that cell through this delegate method as well?

Comment: That's a great question Isuru, worthy of a separate post.  That's what's stumping me right now.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your cell from a xib file, which already connects the buttons to the owner's targets (the view controller).

Comment: That is what I'm doing. Now I want to handle the click action on the cell

Answer (score -3):

In your custom cell just locate your button at IB and make connection with the property.

Now, in the controller at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, what you need, just tag that button, say:

```
(MyCustomCell*)cell.myButton = indexPath.row;
```

Now, after that just set the click event like that:-

```
[(MyCustomCell*)cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(NeedFunctionToCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now, at same view controller, implement that required method, like that:

```
-(void)NeedFunctionToCall:(id)sender
{
 NSLog("Got the event :-> %d, from the cell/button",[sender tag]);
}
```