# How can I use a button in a cell (placed with StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, button, cell, detect

I'm searching for a way to use a button in a cell. I've created it in the prototype cell of my table view but i can't get to detect the cell it's in when I tap on it.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this IBAction is the event handler for when you tap on the button:

```
-   (IBAction) buttonTapped: (UIButton *) sender
    {
       //get parent cell 
       UITableViewCell *cell = [sender findSuperViewWithClass:[UITableViewCell class]];
       //do whatever you want...
    }
```

where you'll need this category:

```
@implementation UIView (SuperView)

- (UIView *)findSuperViewWithClass:(Class)superViewClass
{
    UIView *superView = self.superview;
    UIView *foundSuperView = nil;

    while (nil != superView && nil == foundSuperView) {
        if ([superView isKindOfClass:superViewClass]) {
            foundSuperView = superView;
            break;
        } else {
            superView = superView.superview;
        }
    }
    return foundSuperView;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The cell is not the superview of the button. In iOS 7 there are two other views between the button and the cell (the contentView and a scroll view), in iOS 6 there is one. If you are going to use this approach, you need to look up the superview chain for an object whose class is a UITableViewCell or subclass thereof.

Comment: Too bad, would have been easy that way :p

Comment: @rdelmar: True, I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: @user3362642: Were you able to do it with the updated answer?

Comment: I'm trying but i don't get where the last part is going xD (i'm a beginner in obj-c)

Comment: @Daniel I think i got this, the implementation must go before my TableViewController implementation. It seems to work now, trying to retrieve the row number !

Comment: @Daniel XCode doesn't like the fact that the method is returning an UIView in an UITableViewCell :p

Comment: @Daniel I made a few modifications, and now it works just fine, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

"The way I handle buttons inside custom cells:

- I define an IBAction that I connect to a UIButton event inside the custom cell
- I define a delegate and a delegate method for the cell to handle the button action
- The IBAction calls that delegate method
- When defining your cells in cellAtRow... I set the tableViewController to be the delegate. cell.delegate=self;
- I do whatever action I would like to do inside that delegate method in the tableViewController

"

from [JP Hribovsek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042642/jp-hribovsek)'s answer of [Handle button click inside UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560447/handle-button-click-inside-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, "property delegate not found in UITableViewCell*"

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)buttonOnCellTapped:(id)sender
{        
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.table];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath)
    {
        NSLog(@"BUTTON TAPPED ON SECTION: %d, ROW: %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```